# Game move win percentage

Tags: database

I have two simple file databases. One with the opening game move and if they won or not, and the other one which essentially should just reduce the other database into percentages.

e.g.

```
moves.csv (header="MOVE, DID_WIN, ADDED") -> [(1, true, 16/09/2020), (5, false, 16/09/2020) ...]
```

The "handbook", as it is called, looks like this:

```
handbook.csv (header="MOVE, WIN_PERCENTAGE, LAST_UPDATE") -> 
[(1, some_perc, some_date), (2, some_perc, some_date), (3, some_perc, some_date),
 (4, some_perc, some_date), (5, some_perc, some_date), (6, some_perc, some_date)]
```

There are only six possible starting moves.

Right now, I map each move in the moves.csv to 1 if true, 0 if false, sum those values and divide by total size of that database, and replace this value with the corresponding move in the handbook.

Pseudocode:

```
handbook.get(some_move) = 
    moves.filter(move -> move.move == some_move)
         .map(move -> move.did_win ? 1 : 0)
         .reduce(0, (acc, val) -> acc + val)) / moves.size()
```

Does this actually represent the data I want to get, i.e. the expected value of the win for this move?